# I have 2 errors Expected expression and Expected ')' in expression list as I am a beginner in swiftUI I cannot find the error

Tags: xcode, swiftui

Hello I am following a swiftUI training on the udemy site to learn the basics today I am making a magazine application and I encounter an error Expected expression and the following Expected ')' in expression list being a beginner I don't know exactly how to solve it if you can tell me exactly why there is this error

I thank you

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    // MARK: - PROPERTY
    
    @State private var isAnimating: Bool = false
    @State private var imageScale:  CGFloat = 1
    @State private var imageOffset: CGSize = .zero
    
    // MARK: - FUNCTION
    
    func resetImageState() {
        return withAnimation(.spring()) {
            imageScale = 1
            imageOffset = .zero
            
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - CONTENT
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack{
                // MARK - PAGE IMAGE
                Image("magazine-front-cover")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding()
                    .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.2), radius:12, x: 2, y: 2)
                    .opacity(isAnimating ? 1 : 0)
                    .offset(x: imageOffset.width, y: imageOffset.height)                    .scaleEffect(imageScale)
                // MARK - 1 TAP Gesture
                    .onTapGesture(count: 2, perform: {
                        if imageScale == 1 {
                            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                                imageScale = 5
                            }
                        } else {
                            resetImageState()
                        }
                    })
                // MARK - 2. DRAG GESTURE
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture ()
                            .onChanged { value in
                                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1)) {
                                    imageOffset = value.translation
                                }
                            }
                            .onEnded { _ in
                                if imageScale <= 1 {
                                    resetImageState()
                                }
                            }
                    )
            } // ZSTACK
            .navigationTitle("Pinch & Zoom")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1)) {
                    isAnimating = true
                }
            })
            // MARK: - INFO PANEL
            .overlay(
                InfoPanel(scale: imageScale, offset: imageOffset)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .padding(.top, -60)
                    , alignment: .top
            )
        // MARK: - CONTROLS
        .overlay(
            Group {
                HStack {
            }
                .padding(.bottom, 30)
                , alignment: .bottom
                )
            } //: NAVIGATION
                .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
            }
        }
    
    
    
    // MARK - PREVIEW
    
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
                .previewDevice("iPhone 13")
        }
    }
```

I don't know exactly how to fix the problem

Comment: It just means you deleted a parenthesis somewhere, go through your code and check which is missing, for every open there should be a close. At a quick glance probably the last overlay that seems to need some cleaning up.

Answer (score 1):

You have a leftover Group { without closing curly brackets.

This part of your code:

```
// MARK: - CONTROLS
    .overlay(
        Group {
            HStack {
        }
            .padding(.bottom, 30)
            , alignment: .bottom
            )
```

Should be:

```
// MARK: - CONTROLS
    .overlay(
        HStack {
        }
        .padding(.bottom, 30)
        , alignment: .bottom
        )
```